# How to convert the outputs from the MAX30003 and/or AD8232 ECG modules to millivolts (mV)

Tags: arduino, voltage, conversion, ecg, medical

I have been working with the MAX30003 and AD8232 ECG modules for a while now and I am trying to figure out what the raw outputs from both modules correlate to. I cannot seem to find any information from their datasheets as to what these output values represent and how I can go about converting them into millivolts (mV).

Any assistance or guidance in converting these values to mV would be greatly appreciated.

Here are the datasheets for reference:

MAX30003 - https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX30003.pdf

AD8232 - https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ad8232.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The MAX30003 has 18 bits of resolution as per page 4 of the data sheet and, page 3 tells you the maximum differential AC and DC input ranges. But, of course, you will need to check what decimation you have set as the resolution will move towards 24 bits the more you decimate.

For the AD8232 it produces an analogue output and not a digital output so, somehow, you might be mistaken in thinking it produces a range of number as you state in your question.

Comment: Hello Andy, thank you for your reply. I am a novice at electronics so please excuse my lesser understanding of your answer. What would be the correct formula to input these values?

In relation to the AD8232, is it a case that a ADC conversion formula would calculate the corresponding voltage of the ECG?